# Multiple Choice Column Refiner

Tags: search, search-results, refiner, refinement-panel

I recently created a search refiner for a multiple choice column called MyChoice. For that, i configured the managed property refinable and allowing multiple values.

I did a full crawl and get this:

[image: Search Refiner]

I would expect to hav these two choices separately like this

- Mychoice 1
- MyChoice 2

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for the hint. It seems like the default managed property maps to the other crawled property... KR

Comment: Thank you Sir! I did not realize that :) Worked perfectly

Comment: posted it as an answer, so others could find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to map the "ows_MyChoice" value to your managed property and select Multi-value Refinement Item in the refinement options for that refiner.